# Method to show native picker in Firefox

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use `<input type="date">` fields and I want to change the background color:onfocus at the year, month, a day with CSS,

In Chrome, I use webkit as follow :

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:focus,
input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field:focus,
input[type=date]::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field:focus
{
   background-color: red;
}
```

---

**Is there any translation from WEBKIT to anything supported by FIREFOX to do the same thing ?**